# Issue when trying to perform mvn clean install

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am seeing below errors when trying to run mvn clean install.

I am using maven 3.3.9.

I have tried mvn compile as well. It gives the same errors.

My code is not using ImmutableSet either.

What could be causing the issue?

```
$mvn clean install
constituent[0]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j-simple.jar
constituent[1]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-cli.jar
constituent[32]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.x.jar
constituent[33]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/sisu-plexus.jar
constituent[36]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guava.jar
constituent[37]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.x.jar
constituent[38]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/javax.inject.jar
constituent[41]: file:/usr/share/maven/conf/logging/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet
        at org.apache.maven.extension.internal.CoreExtensionEntry.<init>(CoreExtensionEntry.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.extension.internal.CoreExtensionEntry.discoverFrom(CoreExtensionEntry.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:525)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:281)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
```

Edited to add pom file,

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.1.RELEASE
         
    
    com.demo
    demoproject
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    demoproject
    Demo project

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.18.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What exactly does maven printout with `mvn --version`?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.10.0-30-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: My apache maven shows me in the first line: `Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)` ? ..

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Maven from scratch?

Comment: I have not tried that. I will try that and update. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml please?

Comment: did reinstalling maven help you ?